# Sort an array on date

Tags: php, date, sorting

I know that one can find many posts on sorting arrays on dates. I am struggling for many hours trying to sort mine ('$MyArray') without any success (and I am newbie in PHP, so please forgive me if the answer is obvious):

```
array(9) { 

    [0]=> array(1) {["13 March 2012"]=> string(32) "Commandes Anticorps et Kits 2012" }

    [1]=> array(1) {["4 May 2012"]=> string(23) "Prix de la Chancellerie" } 

    [2]=> array(1) { ["17 April 2012"]=> string(23) "MàJ antivirus Kapersky" }

    [3]=> array(1) { ["14 May 2012"]=> string(24) "Atelier Formation INSERM" }

    [4]=> array(1) { ["14 March 2012"]=> string(13) "Webzine AP-HP" }

    [5]=> array(1) { ["11 April 2011"]=> string(32) "Nouvelle Charte des Publications" }

    [6]=> array(1) { ["23 April 2012"]=> string(28) "BiblioINSERM: Nouveaux Codes" }

    [7]=> array(1) { ["7 March 2012"]=> string(39) "Springer : Protocols également en test" }

    [8]=> array(1) { ["4 October 2011"]=> string(48) "[info.biblioinserm] Archives des titres Springer" } 

    }
```

So I'd like to sort on dates.

Among the various solutions that I have found, I have tried that:

```
function date_compare($a, $b)
{
    $t1 = strtotime($a['datetime']);
    $t2 = strtotime($b['datetime']);

return $t1 - $t2;
}
```

and then called the function:

```
usort($MyArray, 'date_compare');
```

but it doesn't work... :-(

Any help will be much appreciated!!

Comment: What doesn't work, does it return any errors, or does it just not sort?

Comment: can you change the structure of your original $array(9)?

Comment: It just doesn't sort on dates.

Comment: I agree with @sebas, this doesn't work because your dates aren't actually keys in the array, they are keys in independent sub arrays

Comment: @Sebas: I would like to keep it as it is...

Comment: @SupremeDud: yes, I felt that it was the problem. Do you foresee a solution without changing the structure?

Answer (score 2):

In your inner arrays, the date strings are actually the array keys.  So you need to call `strtotime()` on the keys themselves.  This uses `array_keys()` to extract the keys from both comparison arrays, and `array_shift()` to retrieve the first of those (though there's only one).

```
function date_compare($a, $b)
{
    // Remove the first array key (though there should be only one)
    // from both the $a and $b values:
    $akeys = array_keys($a);
    $akey = array_shift($akeys);
    // Could also use
    // $akey = akeys[0];

    $bkeys = array_keys($b);
    $bkey = array_shift($bkeys);
    // Could also use
    // $bkey = bkeys[0];

    // And call strtotime() on the key date values
    $t1 = strtotime($akey);
    $t2 = strtotime($bkey);

    return $t1 - $t2;
}

usort($MyArray, 'date_compare');
```

Comment: Michael, you saved my day!! I have spent so much time and you solved it in 3 min!! It is unbelievable. MANY MANY THANKS!!!!